# Generic Create/Add rest service method (Resteasy)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

I am working on Rest Service project and I am using RestEasy implmentation, and one of my requirement is to implement create (add) service generically.  Given below is the use case.

```
 class Person {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
```

}

```
 class Student extends Person {
private String college;
private String univerisy;
```

}

```
 class Employee extends Person {
private String employer;
private String designation;
```

}

I want to create only one create/add rest service method for all the subclasses of Person (Student, Employee, MovieActor etc.,).

To achieve this functionality I created the rest service method as given below, but I am getting **argument type mismatch errors**

```
 @POST
 @Path("/create")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public <T extends Person> Response create(@PathParam("type") String type, T person) {

 }
```

Client Program to access create method:

```
 Student  student = buildStudent();
 //Define the API URI where API will be accessed
 ClientRequest request = new              ClientRequest("http://myrestservice.com/restservice/rest/student/create/");

 //Set the accept header to tell the accepted response format
 request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, student);

 //Send the request
 ClientResponse response = request.post(Student.class);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to create a generic create method in rest service?

Thanks in advance.